# Need help in setting up PEAR in PHP

Tags: php, pear

I need to emails from my PHP script. The Server, which I have hosted my website on, does not allow the use of core PHP `mail()` function. They say I should write SMTP authentication code for sending emails.

I need to use `require_once('System.php');` at the beginning of my PHP script, but the script execution stops beyond this line. In Apache logs of the Server, the log entry says:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/opt/plesk/php/5.6/share/pear/System.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/kbcsurveyors.com/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/kbcsurveyors.com/preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com/test-smtp-mail.php on line 20\nPHP message: PHP Warning: require_once(/opt/plesk/php/5.6/share/pear/System.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/kbcsurveyors.com/preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com/test-smtp-mail.php on line 20\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error: require_on................

kbcsurveyors.php is the domain that I have hosted.

For SMTP authentication, I need to use PEAR. I had to include the **path/to/pear** in the **php.ini** on the Server. Since, the Server does not allow me to change its own **php.ini**, I copied it to my domain's folder and appended the **path/to/pear** to `include_path`.

Here are commands I used and outputs I had from those commands:

```
shell_exec('cp /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini /var/www/vhosts/kbcsurveyors.com/httpdocs/includes');

shell_exec('pear config-get php_dir');
```

> OUTPUT: /usr/share/pear

```
shell_exec('php --ini');
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
>
> Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/00-ioncube-loader.ini,
>   /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
>   ....

```
echo get_include_path();
```

> OUTPUT .:/opt/plesk/php/5.6/share/pear

```
echo 'Class Exists: '.(class_exists('System', false)) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

> OUTPUT: Class Exists: Yes

But again, require_once 'System.php'; throws the above error in Apache log.

The `phpinfo()`ed a script. It shows the `include_path` as **.:/opt/plesk/php/5.6/share/pear** in both Local Value and Master Value.

What mistake am I making? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use PHPMailer ?

Comment: Best advice is to stop wasting time with a limited hosting plan and use a server where you *can* change the php.ini file. A $5 per month hosting plan with Digital Ocean or even the free years trial with AWS should get you started very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by appending the path shown by 
`shell_exec('pear config-get php_dir');` to `include_path` in **php.ini** of primary domain and all sub-domains.